# Complement function: how to prove surjective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-proofs

Given some set A and a complement function *C(K) = A - K* from the power set of A onto the power set of A, how can I formally prove that it is surjective?

I think I get it, but can't get it on paper. (For context, I have already proven that it is injective.) Every element of the power set of A will be both in the domain and range because the power set of A minus one set yields the rest of its power set, and

*P(A) - empty set = P(A)*

and

*P(A) - P(A) = empty set*

... but that's not equivalent to saying there's a function *f(x) = P(x) - {x}* , right?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that a function is surjective, it's enough to prove that it's bijective; and so it's enough to prove that it has an inverse.

What is the inverse of $C: K \mapsto A \setminus K$?

Comment: Would it be C(K) - A = K?

(Also, I'm trying to prove it's a bijection, which is why I explored its being surjective. Is taking the inverse generally a simpler method?)

Comment: @Leah It depends; sometimes it's easier to show "injective and surjective", sometimes it's easier to show "has an inverse". In this case, the inverse is very easy to state, so it's easier to show that it's an inverse. The inverse is $C$ itself (that is, $C$ is self-inverse).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your question.

Let $T,S \subset A$.

$C: P(A) \rightarrow P(A).$

$T \mapsto A$ \ $T.$

Surjective:

Let $S \in P(A)$, range, then

$A$ \ $S \in P(A).$

Choose $A$ \ $S \in P(A)$, domain: Then

$C(A$ \ $S) = A$ \ $(A$ \ $S) =S,$ hence surjective.

Comment: Sorry - I appreciate your response, but am not sure I follow yours either. Would you be so kind as to talk me through the portion after the imaging?

Comment: Leah.Pick any set S in the  P(A),  range .We find an element in the domain P(A), A\S whose image is C(A\S)=S. Every S in P(A) is the image of an element in the domain.Surjective.Your thoughts.